# 'int' object not callable when opening a file in python

Tags: python

I am getting what seems to be an odd error when trying to open a file in python.  I am simply trying to open a csv:

`with open(filename, 'a') as history:`

filename is simply a string pointing the file:

`filename = file_path + "\\dashboards\\" + csv_file`

it is identified as a string in python, but whenever I get to the open statement, it returns:

`TypeError}'int' object not callable`

That seems odd as it is just a csv file, with a header.  Has anyone run across this before?
``

Comment: Have defined and `open = 12345` or something like that anywhere in your code!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have defined `open` as a variable somewhere else with an int value. This is causing the error message.

Comment: Yes, thank you, rookie mistake.  I was parsing test status information, and incorrectly named one of the variables 'open'.  Variable renamed, problem solved